# Is it possible to use javascript popup to accept input in php

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to use javascript popup to accept input in PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function popup(){
var answer = prompt ("What is your name ?","")

    return answer
}
// -->
</script>

<?php 

$value = echo "popup()"; // error

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but probably not how you expect it to.

In your code, the PHP will be executed on the server before the page is sent to the browser. The `popup()` function will only be executed after the page loads and the user enters the input.

If you take input via a JS prompt, you'll have to make a synchronous or asynchronous request to a PHP page on the server.

Check the [jQuery ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not like that. By the time the page loads and the JavaScript runs, the PHP is already done.

You can however get that information, than load it in a page with AJAX, process it, then spit it back out.

Answer (score 0):

When you embed code in a .php page there are also some html and javascript code.

When a php page is requested its `<?php // Your Code ?>` is executed on the server and and may or maynot output some html on that line. After that the neat and clean html page is returned to the browser. So your requirement is not possible this way.

If you want to do this then you have to send a server request through AJAX.
For more info look in `AJAX` section of [Jquery](http://jquery.com) site.